# Determining Wet Well Service Area using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, buffer, web-service, service-area

I am using ArcMap 10.1

I have a wet well with a known ground elevation. I am trying to determine the service area of that area based on the assumptions that the wet well is 20 feet deep and that my minimum slope is .5%. [image: My crummy drawing trying to illustrate the problem]I do not know which way my pipe will go so I want to create a buffer service area with the possible distance in all directions.

[image: Buffer example]

Comment: Please take the [Tour] to learn more about how the site works.  I think you should [edit] your question to provide clarifications like this.

Answer (score 1):

I hope each of the pictures below is self-explanatory

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Note I tried to convert feet to metres here

[image]

Result might be very different to what you are expecting, especially on a steep slope:

[image]